# Need to iterate over queryset of student answers and provide individual "feedback" form field for each one

Tags: django, forms, for-loop, django-models, django-forms

I am building a homework database application that will make answering, grading and correcting homework simpler than it is now.

To do this I have forms for students to fill in an answer to a question that has been assigned to them, the question is then marked as ready to be graded and the teacher's view can then see all the questions that are ready to be graded per assignment.

The trouble that I am having is inserting a form field into each answer where feedback could be given; I suppose the simplest way would be to load one question and its answer per page and have a feedback form field there, but what I would like to do is to iterate over all the questions that have been answered on a given assignment and display them all on one page so that they can be graded quickly.

I have tried to insert just a form field into the for loop, and had some success, but when I submit I can't pull the question id out of the loop to populate the (required) foreign key pointing from the feedback model to the original question-answer.

I've toyed with multiple forms on a page, I've tried to create a forum type answer and response, I've tried to grab the original answer id from inside the for loop and send it back to the form, but I'm starting to wonder if I'm just not seeing some simple thing that is happening behind the scenes to stop it from working.

```
@login_required
@teacher_required
def list_ungraded_assignment_questions_by_scheduled_assignment(request, scheduled_assignment):
        need_to_be_evaluated_student_assignment_questions = StudentAssignmentQuestion.objects.filter(student_scheduled_class_assignment=scheduled_assignment).filter(needs_to_be_reviewed_by_teacher=True)
        need_to_be_evaluated_student_assignment_question_ids = []
        for assignment_question in need_to_be_evaluated_student_assignment_questions:
            need_to_be_evaluated_student_assignment_question_ids.append(assignment_question.id)

        student_assignment_question_answers = StudentAssignmentQuestionAnswer.objects.filter(student_assignment_question__in=need_to_be_evaluated_student_assignment_question_ids)

        context = {"need_to_be_evaluated_student_assignment_questions": need_to_be_evaluated_student_assignment_questions, "student_assignment_question_answers": student_assignment_question_answers}
        return render(request, "accelegraded/list_ungraded_assignment_questions_by_scheduled_assignment.html", context)
```

```
{% for student_assignment_question_answer in student_assignment_question_answers %}
                {% if student_assignment_question_answer.student_assignment_question.id == need_to_be_evaluated_student_assignment_question.id %}
                    <h6 style="background-color:DodgerBlue;">ANSWER: {{ student_assignment_question_answer }}</h6>
                    <h6 style="background-color:DodgerBlue;" ALIGN=RIGHT>Answered On: {{ student_assignment_question_answer.date_created }}</a></h6>
                    {% for student_assignment_question_answer_evaluation in student_assignment_question_answer_evaluations %}
                        {% if student_assignment_question_answer_evaluation.student_assignment_question_answer.id == student_assignment_question_answer.id %}
                            <h6 style="background-color:LightGreen;">RESPONSE: {{ student_assignment_question_answer_evaluation }}</h6>
                            <h6 style="background-color:LightGreen;">BY: {{ student_assignment_question_answer_evaluation.answer_evaluation_by }}</h6>
                            <h6 style="background-color:LightGreen;">AT: {{ student_assignment_question_answer_evaluation.answer_evaluation_by }}</h6>
                        {% endif %} 
                    {% endfor %}
            <div>
                <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="#">Correct</a>
                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="#">Partial</a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="#">Incorrect</a>
                <div class="content-section">
                    <form method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Teacher Response</legend>
                            {{ form|crispy }}
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
                {% endif %}                 
            {% endfor %}
```

The error that I get when I try to save input in the form is that a default value of the question-answer is not being returned and I have no idea how to return it back to the form to populate the model.

Answer (score 0):

You should take advantage of the relationship between your models.

```
questions = StudentAssignmentQuestion.objects.filter(
    student_scheduled_class_assignment=scheduled_assignment,
    needs_to_be_reviewed_by_teacher=True,
).prefetch_related(
    'studentassignmentquestionanswer_set', # Or StudentAssignmentQuestionAnswer.question.related_name
)
```

Then you can iterate over the list as such:

```
for question in questions:
    for answer in question.studentassignmentquestionanswer_set.all():
        print(answer)
```

Side note, I think your member names are a bit too verbose. For example `needs_to_be_reviewed_by_teacher` could be `needs_review` or if you need to distinguish that it's only relevant for a teacher and not an admin, then `needs_teacher_review`.